# Radio button causing crash of extenrion

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome-extension, radio-button

I'm trying to insert some twitter bootstrap radio buttons in a chrome extension, but whenever I click on the inactive button, the extension reloads and the buttons remain as before.

I've noticed in the brief moment before the reloading that the extension console was outputting the source-scr self secuirity issue.

Just to be sure I've completely removed all js from the extension (not even 1 line), but with my surprise the problem is still there. Not the security error though.

I have no idea of what's causing the problem...

Here's one of the radio btn

```
<span class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio" style="width:100%">
    <button class="btn btn-inverse" style="width:50%">First</button>
    <button class="btn btn-inverse active" style="width:50%">Second</button>
</span>
```

At the moment there is NO js at all in the whole extension, before it was called in the `head`.

The problem appears when I click on `First`, which is the inactive btn.

Comment: With only this much of information even we do not have an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've figured out that the problem was that the radio elements are inside a `form` element

I've rewritten bit by bit the whole thing and the problem appeared onl when I wrapped the radio btns inside the form.

I have no idea of why that's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the Content Security Policy, which prevents the use of inline style.
You can see more information on the [CSP for Chrome extensions page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html).

You can relax your CSP for styles by adding `style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';` in your manifest file.

```
"content_security_policy": "default-src 'self' style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"
```

This will allow you to keep using inline style in your extension.

Comment: I've added a solution, I'm still not 100% sure of what's going on though. I've tried to add the CSP as you suggested, but the problem persisted if the radio btns are inside the form..